# What are chunks, samples and frames when using pyaudio

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio, sampling, pyaudio

After going through the documentation of pyaudio and reading some other articles on the web, I am confused if my understanding is correct.

This is the code for audio recording found on pyaudio's site:

```
import pyaudio
import wave

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

and if I add these lines then I am able to play whatever I recorded:

```
play=pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream_play=play.open(format=FORMAT,
                      channels=CHANNELS,
                      rate=RATE,
                      output=True)
for data in frames: 
    stream_play.write(data)
stream_play.stop_stream()
stream_play.close()
play.terminate()
```

1. "RATE" is the number of samples collected per second.
2. "CHUNK" is the number of frames in the buffer.
3. Each frame will have 2 samples as "CHANNELS=2".
4. Size of each sample is 2 bytes, calculated using the function: `pyaudio.get_sample_size(pyaudio.paInt16)`.
5. Therefore size of each frame is 4 bytes.
6. In the "frames" list, size of each element must be 1024*4 bytes, for example, size of `frames[0]` must be 4096 bytes. However, 
   `sys.getsizeof(frames[0])` returns `4133`, but `len(frames[0])` returns `4096`.
7. `for` loop executes `int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)` times, I cant understand why. [Here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13728/what-are-chunks-when-recording-a-voice-signal/24249#24249?newreg=f46f1af2f2e84ba1bceb57fb257d8587) is the same question answered by "Ruben Sanchez" but I cant be sure if its correct as he says `CHUNK=bytes`. And according to his explanation, it must be `int(RATE / (CHUNK*2) * RECORD_SECONDS)` as `(CHUNK*2)` is the number of samples read in buffer with each iteration.
8. Finally when I write `print frames[0]`, it prints gibberish as it tries to treat the string to be ASCII encoded which it is not, it is just a stream of bytes. So how do I print this stream of bytes in hexadecimal using `struct` module? And if later, I change each of the hexadecimal value with values of my choice, will it still produce a playable sound?

Whatever I wrote above was my understanding of the things and many of them maybe wrong.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

1. "RATE" is the "sampling rate", i.e. the number of *frames* per second
2. "CHUNK" is the (arbitrarily chosen) number of *frames* the (potentially very long) signals are split into in this example
3. Yes, each frame will have 2 samples as "CHANNELS=2", but the term "samples" is seldom used in this context (because it is confusing)
4. Yes, size of each sample is 2 bytes (= 16 bits) in this example
5. Yes, size of each frame is 4 bytes
6. Yes, each element of "frames" should be 4096 bytes. `sys.getsizeof()` reports the storage space needed by the Python interpreter, which is typically a bit more than the actual size of the raw data.
7. `RATE * RECORD_SECONDS` is the number of *frames* that should be recorded. Since the `for` loop is not repeated for each *frame* but only for each *chunk*, the number of loops has to be divided by the chunk size `CHUNK`. This has nothing to do with *samples*, so there is no factor of `2` involved.
8. If you really want to see the hexadecimal values, you can try something like `[hex(x) for x in frames[0]]`. If you want to get the actual 2-byte numbers use the format string `'<H'` with the `struct` module.

You might be interested in my tutorial about reading WAV files with the `wave` module, which covers some of your questions in more detail: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mgeier/python-audio/blob/master/audio-files/audio-files-with-wave.ipynb

Comment: for point 4,5: how are the channels represented in each sample? Is it linear, e.g., [s1a, s1b, s2a, s2b] or interleaved, e.g, [s1a, s2a, s1b, s2b]?

Comment: @Koffiman With PyAudio the samples are interleaved. The underlying PortAudio library supports a flag [paNonInterleaved](http://www.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/portaudio_8h.html#a1d79f0b88812cef5364b276dbbc898b5) to change that, but this is typically not available in the Python wrappers. Note that `paNonInterleaved` uses separate pointers for each channel, i.e. the whole audio data is not necessarily contained in a single contiguous block of memory.