# What do data in pyaudio stream mean?

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I use pyaudio library to read sound from audiocard. I use the following code

```
stream = pyaudio.PyAudio().open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=2,
                                rate=44100, input=True,
                                frames_per_buffer=1024)

CHUNK = 1024
frames = []
for i in range(0, int(44100 / 1024 * seconds)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
```

I want to know what is one frame, what is one chunk and what is their format. It seems like there's no such info in the library description.

Comment: https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.Stream.read

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36116237/.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody hopping in later:

A sample is a single float32 value that represents the value of the audio stream at each specific point in time, in a specific channel (left or right, if in the case of stereo).

**A frame**, is the set of all values for all channels that will play at a specific point in time.

Taken from : [Mozilla webaudio description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Basic_concepts_behind_Web_Audio_API)

Format: paInt16 is a format to store those sample data as a 16-bit integer value.

DATA: It is the number of frames specified by CHUNK value you are taking at one time from the stream. Think of stream as collection of frames.